# SSH port forwarding not working for websocket

Tags: ssh, websocket, port, forwarding, tunnel

I'm running a web service on serverA:8890, this includes the regular HTTP service and websocket services. I'm trying to set up the SSH port forwarding from serverB to serverA, so I can access the ServerA's service through SSH tunnel.

Here is my command:

```
ssh -f user@serverA -i user.pem -L 2000:serverB:8890 -N
```

When I connect to ServerB:2000, I can see all the regular web services, but the websocket part is not working.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I believe your tunnel needs to be:

```
ssh -f user@serverA -i user.pem -L 2000:serverA:8890 -N
```

Comment: wooooohoooooooo thought I was the only one with the issue

ssh -f user@serverA -i user.pem -L 2000:serverA:8890 -N

should be marked as the accepted answer. thank you so much @Greg Bell